# Windows how does the "Path" environment variable work?

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, environment-variables, command-prompt

I recently added python to my environment variables when this question popped into my head. When I type "python" into command prompt, windows seems to know which file to run. However, I added python into this environment variable called "Path", and never specified "python" anywhere.

I don't understand how windows knows what I want when I type "python". Could someone help clear this up?

Comment: For each directory in your `PATH`, it looks for an executable file with a base name of "python".  It uses the first one it finds.

Comment: Take a look at [PEP 397 – Python launcher for Windows](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/)

Comment: In the shell, the `PATH` search looks for the base name, if it has a file extension, plus the file extensions from `PATHEXT` (e.g. .COM, .EXE, .BAT). If you need to match files without an extension, add a "." (no quotes) entry to `PATHEXT`. To prevent implicitly searching the working directory, define `NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath` as any value (e.g. make it "True" or "1"). You can explicitly add the working directory (i.e. a "." entry, without quotes) to a safer position in `PATH`, such as the end of your per-user `PATH` in the environment variable editor.

Comment: In the API, `CreateProcessW` will also search for an executable if `lpApplicationName` is `NULL`. This search looks for the base name (including a name without a file extension) and the base name plus ".EXE". It does not use `PATHEXT`. It prepends some directories to `PATH`: the application directory, current directory, and system directories, i.e. `"%__APPDIR__%;.;%SystemRoot%\System32;%SystemRoot%\System;%SystemRoot%"`. Like with CMD, you can make it exclude the current directory by defining `NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PATH** is an environment variable that holds values related to current user and operating system. It specifies the directories in which executable programs are located. so when you type python window gets its executable from **PATH**. hence, you won't need to type the whole path to the file on command line.